# A Job For Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Greetings!

I have a class which is used like a cache:

```
public sealed class MyCache<T> : IDisposable
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim theLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private Dictionary<int, T> theCache = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    public void Add(int key, T value)
    {
        // ... logic/code to add to the dictionary
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        theLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            theCache.Clear();
        }
        finally
        {
            theLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

This cache is used many times, so there are often multiple instances of this at any given time.

Example 1:

```
public static class SpecialPageCache
{
    public static MyCache<string> SpecialPage = new MyCache<string>();
}
```

Example 2:

```
public static class DdListCache
{
    public static MyCache<List<int, string>> DdlList = new MyCache<List<int, string>>();
}
```

And so on.

I have a service that can clear the caches on-demand, but unfortunately, each one has to be cleared like so:

```
private void ClearThemAll()
{
    SpecialPageCache.SpecialPage.Clear();
    DdListCache.DdlList.Clear();
    // repeat for all other caches that may exist ...
}
```

How can I use reflection (or something else?) to call each cache's Clear() method without having to explcitly do it for each one like I do in the above ClearThemAll() method?

Answer (score 3):

Ick. You'd have to go through all the types in the assembly that you're interested in, and check all the static fields. This is made even more interesting because it's a generic type. Your life will be simpler if you have a nongeneric base class:

```
public abstract class MyCache : IDisposable
{
    public abstract void Clear();
}

public sealed class MyCache<T> : MyCache
{
    // ...
}
```

Then at least it's relatively easy to detect whether the type of a particular field is a `MyCache`, fetch its value and call `Clear` on it without messing around with reflection over generic types.

This is generally a nasty problem though - are you sure you want to clear all the caches like this, without really "understanding" which caches you're clearing?

Comment: That kind of leads into a second question where in some situations, certain cache's may need to be cleared while others don't have to be.

Comment: So have a ClearableCache and NonclearableCache, or pass an argument to Clear() that allows it to make the decision.

Comment: Though following on from Jon's final remark, you might want the caches to (optionally) respond to events, rather than force the cache clear.

Comment: Downvoting because I think storing references to all the caches is a better solution than reflection

Comment: Jim: the "service that can clear the caches on-demand" presumably already has this list, surely?

Comment: Jim: Thanks for explaining the downvote. I hope I made it fairly clear in the answer that I didn't really like the use of reflection here. I agree that if it's feasible, a list of references to caches to clear would be nicer.

Comment: @Mark: with the OP's current design each new cache requires an explicit, hard-coded reference, which is probably what led him to consider reflection.  I'm just pointing out that creating and storing the references at run time instead of compile time is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
public interface ICache : IDisposable
{
    void Clear();
}

public interface ICache<T> : ICache
{
}

public abstract class CacheBase<T> : ICache<T>
{

}

public sealed class SpecialPageCache : CacheBase<string>
{
    internal SpecialPageCache()
    {
    }

}

public static class CacheFactory
{
    private static List<ICache> cacheList = new List<ICache>();

    public static TCache Create<TCache>()
        where TCache : ICache, new()
    {
        var result = new TCache();
        cacheList.Add(result);
        return result;
    }

    public static void ClearAll()
    {
        cacheList.ForEach((c) => c.Clear());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store references to all of your instanced caches in a list. Then iterate same list, and call Clear on each MyCache. =)

Answer (score 1):

Reflection sounds nasty. Without knowing more about your object lifetime, would the following work?

```
public abstract class MyCacheBase : IDisposable {
    public static List<MyCache> caches = new List<MyCache>();

    public MyCacheBase() {
        caches.Add(this); // Add all constructed caches to the list
    }

    public static void ClearAllCaches() {
        foreach (MyCache cache in cache) // clear all constructed
            cache.Clear();               // caches in the list.
    }

    public void Finalize() {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        caches.Remove(this);  // Remove disposed classes from the list
    }

    public abstract void Clear();
}

public sealed class MyCache<T> : MyCacheBase
{
    // Rest of the implementation
}
```

(Thanks to Jon for noting the genericity. Almost missed it.)

If you want to have something like user specific caches you could add a user specific CacheFactory which would keep track of the caches created through it and its ClearAll() method would only clear those caches.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to specifcally clear them are they using resources which need to be released ?

I'm wondering if you couldnt use the System.WeakReference so that the cache is garbarge collected as and when ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This sound really familiar to how Inversion of Control containers work.  Why not just have something like a

`Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<int, object>>`

All of the functions would then take a type T and then use that type to look up the appopriate dictionary.  One static MyCache could handle all your type and it could be disposed with one call.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do reflection then you'd do something like this:

```
List<object> caches;
foreach (object obj in caches)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("Clear");

    // Object does not have a public instance method named "Clear"
    if (m == null) { continue; }

    m.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
}
```